# picoblaze Celsius to fahrenheit conversion in assembly

Tags: assembly, fpga, picoblaze

I want to perform on picoblaze (FPGA)  Celsius to fahrenheit conversion in assembly using the following conversion formula Fahrenheit = (Celsius * 9 / 5) + 32. But I am not able even to make simply multiplication of two number in assembly language. Can someone help me ? I have seen through google how to perform this conversion in assembly but picoblaze has it's own specific syntax.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/ug129.pdf 
at page 27 is written multiplication code but I do not understand how to use it

Comment: write it in C and compile it then use that.  or just call a C function from asm.

Comment: @old_timer There is no C-to-PicoBlaze compiler.

Comment: hmm took seconds to find one.  same amount of time as it it took to write that comment.

Comment: @old_timer I wrote [a Bachelor thesis about PicoBlaze](https://repozitorij.etfos.hr/islandora/object/etfos:4489/datastream/PDF/download) a few months ago. If there was a C-to-PicoBlaze compiler, I would know that.

Comment: See also [Handling overflow in 8-bit multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77733324/471129)

Answer (score 1):

```
;Let's say Celsius is on input 0
;and you are supposed to output
;Fahrenheit on output 0.

address 0
input s0, 0
load s1, 0
load s2, 9
multiplication_by_9:
add s1, s0
sub s2, 1
jump nz, multiplication_by_9
load s2, 0
division_by_5:
add s2, 1
sub s1, 5
jump nc, division_by_5
add s2, 32'd
output s2, 0
jump 0
```

You can try it in [the PicoBlaze Simulator in JavaScript I made](https://picoblaze-simulator.sourceforge.io/).

EDIT: I've started [a new thread asking how to improve that program to work with a wider range of inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77731225/making-a-celsius-to-fahrenheit-converter-in-picoblaze-assembly-work-with-a-wider?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score -1):

I can recommend you to have a look at [Instant SoC](https://www.fpga-cores.com/instant-soc/) instead. You only need to write C++ and since the hardware is optimized to the code it will be almost as small as Picoblaze.
I use Instant SoC instead of both Microblaze and Picoblaze now.